# ASP.NET MVC CheckboxListFor values not posting back

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In desperation, I created a CheckboxListFor method as follows (I ripped this off from somewhere, probably here).

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> expression, MultiSelectList multiSelectList, object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            //Derive property name for checkbox name
            var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            string propertyName = body.Member.Name;

            //Get currently select values from the ViewData model
            IEnumerable<TProperty> list = expression.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);

            //Convert selected value list to a List<string> for easy manipulation
            var selectedValues = new List<string>();

            if (list != null)
            {
                selectedValues = new List<TProperty>(list).ConvertAll(i => i.ToString());
            }

            //Create div
            var divTag = new TagBuilder("div");
            divTag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), true);

            //Add checkboxes
            foreach (SelectListItem item in multiSelectList)
            {
                divTag.InnerHtml += String.Format("<div><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"{0}\" id=\"{0}_{1}\" " +
                                                    "value=\"{1}\" {2} /><label for=\"{0}_{1}\">{3}</label></div>",
                                                    propertyName,
                                                    item.Value,
                                                    selectedValues.Contains(item.Value) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "",
                                                    item.Text);
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(divTag.ToString());
        }
```

I call it like so:

```
 <h2>Rights</h2>
    <div>
        @Html.CheckBoxListFor(m=>m.SelectedRights, Model.Rights)
    </div>
```

And it renders out correctly. However, the selected values do not post back. How do I go about fixing this? Can anybody suggest a good starting point?

**Update:**
I thought it might be good to add some more detail, as this thing may have multiple issues.

The ids of the checkboxes are coming out like "SelectedRights_6".
Here's the ViewModel I'm currently using.

```
 public class RoleSingleViewModel : BaseEntitySingleViewModel
    {
    public override int ListViewColSpan
    {
        get { return 6; }
    }

    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Sites {get;set;}
    public int SiteId{get;set;}
    public string SiteText{get;set;}
    public override string TypeName
    {
        get { return "Role"; }
    }

    public MultiSelectList Rights { get{return new MultiSelectList(AllRights, "Key", "Value", SelectedRights);}}
    public List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> AllRights { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> SelectedRights { get; set; }
}
```

Also, the update method on the controller is like so. I set a breakpoint on the line where the exception is thrown and examined updateItem. The value of Rights, AllRights, and SelectedRights are not filled in (which is, I guess, expected behavior). I'm thinking my problem might be with the structure of my ViewModel. How should I change it?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(RoleSingleViewModel updateItem)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
```

Comment: Well, first look at the rendered HTML in the browser and see what the names of the controls are being rendered with.  Then check the posted values with fiddler or in your code to see if those are there.  If they are, then your problem is likely a naming convention mismatch.  How do you know the values are not being posted?  Post your controller code that receives the values.

Comment: The ids look like "SelectedRights_6".

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **ID attribute** from the check-box. When it posting the **selected values(only)** to server, it will be array of integer or string(I never tested with string). So your model/parameter should have the same property name(**and it should be an array**).

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to initialise a collection in order for the results to bind, i.e. the For property has to be initialised before binding. The model binder will not create the collection, but it will add the items if you have already defined the collection:

On your model

```
private IEnumerable<int> checkedItems = new List<int>();

public IEnumerable<int> CheckedItems
{ 
    get { 
        return this.checkedItems ;
    }

    set {
        this.checkedItems  = value;
    }
}
```

And in the razor view

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(CheckedItems, ...)
```